# plot flot chart points for only selected few in series

Tags: flot, points

I have a flot chart with 5 series of data. Each series is one year with each split into months. The Y-Axis is cost and the X-axis months. Sometimes there is a user message within the data for a particular month(s) within any of the series. What I would like to do is show points on any particular series but only if the user message is not null, For example if June 2012 has a user message show a point for this month in that year only. Is this possible as at the moment I can only turn plot points on or off for each complete series, i.e 12 plot points.

Comment: `flot` does not have any per point options.  You'll have to filter your data and remove points that don't fit your criteria.

Comment: But I need the points plotted for each month of the year.

Comment: I don't understand, I thought you wanted *only the ones with user messages* plotted?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I should have been more elaborate. Each series is a line graph split over 12 months so there will always be 12 intersections or points, I have set the radius to zero for each point. what I now want to do is make a point more visible, say with radius of 4 wherever there is a user message assigned to the point. Is this at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split your data into two seperate series.

The first is all the data with only lines showing.

The second has only those points with "userMsg" and has only points showing.

Set the color of the two series to the same color.

```js
var myData = [{point: [1,Math.random() * 100], userMsg: "One"}, 
              {point: [2,Math.random() * 100]}, 
              {point: [3,Math.random() * 100], userMsg: "Three"},
              {point: [4,Math.random() * 100], userMsg: "Four"},
              {point: [5,Math.random() * 100]}];

var series1 = {data: $.map(myData, function(i){return [i.point];}),
               points: {show: false},
               lines: {show: true},
               color: 'rgb(255, 100, 123)'};

var series2 = {data: $.map(myData, function(i){if (i.userMsg) return [i.point];}),
               points: {show: true, radius: 8},
               lines: {show: false},
               color: 'rgb(255, 100, 123)'};

somePlot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ series1, series2 ], {});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>

<div id="placeholder" style="width:300px; height:300px"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mark, this has worked out quite well so many thanks for taking the time to put this solution together.A new issue has now come to light tho in that the labels for user messages do not function as I would like. I have therefore disabled showing labels for user messages but turning off the corresponding line data causes the message to not show on hover

Comment: I have therefore disabled showing labels for user messages but turning off the corresponding line data by hiding the label causes the message to not show on hover. I suspect this is due to the tooltip being assigned to the line data, which is shown using the year (year = item.series.label). Any ideas greatly appreciated.